# Why can I off a mousedown event, but not its chained mouseup event?

Tags: jquery, chaining, mousedown, event-listener, mouseup

I have two chained mouse-events:

```
$('body > form').on("mousedown", function(e){ 
    //Do stuff 
}).on("mouseup", function(){
    /*More stuff, including
       window.addEventListener(...
    */  
});
```

However, when I try to `off()` them both from another external function, I can only `off()` `mousedown`, but not `mouseup`, whose functionality continues to work.

Could that nested `addEventListener` be preventing me from offing its event?  (

By the way, it doesn't matter how I 
chain: (`$().off().off();`), or unchain (`$().off(); $().off();`), or combine (`$().off(A B);`) or reverse (A B <-> B A) the elements; consistently, `off(mousedown)` works, but never `off(up)`.

### Here's my full JS code:

*(The problematic part is the 2nd script, at the end:)*

```
<script>
function comment() {

    $('body > form').on("mousedown.markerPlacer", function(e){   
     //Place the cursor marker on the screen 

        var newComment2 = $('<div id="newComm" class="marker" class="deg45" &uarr;</div>');
        $('form').append(newComment2);  

    }).on("mouseup", function(){   
    //Now use the Q-key to rotate the marker.

       window.addEventListener("keydown", extraKey, false); 
       window.addEventListener("keyup", keysReleased2, false); 

            function extraKey(e) {
                var deg = e.keyCode;  
                    if (deg == 81)  { //81 is the keycode, which codes for Q
                        $('#newComm').attr('class', 'marker').addClass('deg0'); 
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    };  
                    e.preventDefault(); 
            };                 
            function keysReleased2(e) {
                e.keyCode = false;
            };
    });  
};
</script>

<script>
function dismissComment() {
        $('body > form').off("mousedown mouseup");    
}
</script>
```

Comment: because the .on does not return anything.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. We can't see how you are attempting to use `off()` without proper code context

Comment: @Bindrid, what does that mean, and why would it make a difference, since  they're both .on events?

Comment: @charlietfl, Sure, but that'll M-C-V answer will take me a few minutes to produce.

Comment: Take a look at https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: My guess is you are hoping that `off()` will remove whatever listener you create inside the `on()` ...but that is not the case. Once you add a listener it will remain until it is removed

Comment: off $.off() will take of all  events for the object unless you put limits in the parameters such as .off("click")

Comment: OK, so my full code is posted.  Hmm.  If you're right, then I have to remove that event listener.  The problem is that if I post the required 2 lines of code.............. . . .  `window.removeEventListener("keydown", extraKey, false);` 
`window.removeEventListener("keyup", keysReleased2, false);`    ..............anywhere, then I can only push Q to turn the marker once.  Repeat-turns are disabled.  But maybe I can figure out a way.

Comment: Is there a better way to do this (trigger extraKey() & keysReleased2())  without Event listeners?  I tried chaining `.on(mousedown).on(keydown).on(keyup)`, but that only maed the keydown and keyup events not work, so that I couldn't rotate the marker at all..

Comment: @Bindrid - Thanks!  I'll have  to learn about plugins!  (I don't know the first thing about them.)

Comment: this worked:  $("button").on("mousedown",function () { $("span").css("background-color", "red") }).on("mouseup", function () { $("span").css("backgroundColor", "blue") })

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity I wrote a similar chained mousedown and mouseup as shown in your code.
And I unbind them on button click. 
It seems to work fine and I'm not able to reproduce your issues.
It's able to "off" both mousedown and mouseup event listener.

```
$("#testMe")
  .on("mousedown", function(e) {
    appendText(getButton(e.button) + " | " + $(this).attr("id") + " | " + "mouseDOWN | " + new Date());
  })
  .on("mouseup", function(e) {
    appendText(getButton(e.button) + " | " + $(this).attr("id") + " | " + "mouseUP | " + new Date());

    $(document).off("keydown keyup");
    $(document).on("keydown", keydown_pressed);
    $(document).on("keyup", keyup_pressed);
  });
```

**Unbind / "off" code**

```
$("#unbind").click(function(e) {
  $("#testMe").off("mousedown mouseup");
  $(document).off("keydown keyup");
});
```

On **page load**, mousedown and mouseup are attached to input textbox.

[image: page load event listener - textbox]

After **mouseclick on textbox**, window keydown and keyup event listeners are added.

[image: document keydown and keyup event]

After I **"off" or unbind**, all event listeners are removed.

[image: after unbind]

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/07xx4aze/4/)